# What is the difference of entropy when used with discrete and continuous random variable X?

Tags: random-variables, entropy

Entropy for a continuous random variable that has Gaussian distribution is defined as:

$H(X)=-\int p(x)lnp(x)dx$

after some calculations it becomes:

$H(X)=\frac{1}{2}(ln(2\pi \sigma^{2})+1)$

After this book says:

> The last inequality is according to the variance of a standard normal distribution $\sigma^2=\int p(x)(x-u)^{2}dx$
>
> Note that unlike the entropy for discrete variable which is always non-negative when $\sigma^{2}<\frac{1}{2\pi e}$, $H(X)<0$

And claims that one property which holds for the entropy of any discrete random variable but doesn't hold here is indicated here.

I understood every calculation and formulas that are derived. But I can not see what is that property is.

Comment: If $\sigma$^2 is strictly bounded as such then the argument for $\ln$ is $<1/e<1$ so that $H(X)<0$ as stated. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @NapD.Lover My question is, what is the property we proved here that differs the continuous and discrete random variables X's for this case? and how exactly we showed it?

Comment: “note that unlike the entropy for *discrete variable*, which is *always non-negative*, when $\sigma^2<....$ [then] $H(X)<0$” i.e. the entropy is *not* non-negative for our continuous Gaussian RV.

Comment: @NapD.Lover I don't know what to extract from what you wrote. Can you explain further? As an answer maybe?

Comment: I honestly think I am being as clear as possible. *You have to explain what you specifically do not understand about my comments*. The entropy of a *discrete random variable* is *non-negative*. You do know what “non-negative” means right and what a “discete RV” is, right? But here they show this does not always hold for continuous RVs, i.e. they exhibited an example of a continuous RV (a Gaussian one) that has *negative* entropy, i.e. $H(X)<0$ (but only when $\sigma^2$ bounded appropriately).

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but first I must ask you to be not aggressive. Can you do that? At your second comment you literally copied a sentence from question and make a statement afterwards, not even included how you concluded. From your last comment I understand the main difference is continuous RV can be negative, whereas discrete can't. One of the questions was "How exactly we showed it?" which is more essential part which didn't addressed. I think I'm very clear, plain English and you should have no difficulty understanding it.

Comment: “how exactly we showed [a continuous RV can have negative *entropy*]” was already addressed in my first comment but to reiterate again: If $\sigma^2 < (2\pi e)^{-1}$ then the expression for $H(X)$ that you wrote for Gaussian $X$ is negative since then $2\pi \sigma^2 <1$ and $\ln x <0$ for all $0<x<1$. Again, I had already outlined this in my first comment so I am not going to reply any further (and someone just answered with essentially the same reasoning in my comments) so best of luck. Apologies if my tone came off as aggressive, I was trying to be direct, not aggressive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to integrate two things. The formula you found for $H(X)$ at the end, and the formula you found for variance.

As stated at your book, when you insert $\sigma^{2}< \frac{1}{2 \pi e}$ the $ln(2 \pi \sigma^2)$ inside your latest entropy function can become less than 1. So your function becomes negative. It seems like this is what you missed here.

Comment: I think this is a clear question, why it got down-voted?